# AngularJS, controller is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Making a very simple application in angular, and everytime I try to do this I run into this problem and never know how to solve it.

App.js is this:

```
angular.module('Euclid',
        ['ui.bootstrap',
        'ngRoute'])
.controller('mainController', function($scope){
})
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController',
        controllerAs: 'homeCtrl'
    });
}]);
```

Just some basic routing, nothing in the controller.

Now, that 'HomeController' is set up like this:

```
var HomeController = function($scope){
    var self = this;
    // code here
};
angular.module('Euclid').controller('HomeController', HomeController);
```

And my index.html is set up like so:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="Euclid">
    <body ng-controller="mainController" ng-cloak>
        <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <div class="container">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error in all it's glory is "Argument 'HomeController' is not a function, got undefined". I can not for the life of me figure out where it is getting undefined.

Comment: You seem to be missing the script files for `ngRoute`, `ui.bootstrap` and wherever your `HomeController` is defined

Comment: Show the index.html file

Answer (score 0):

I created a `plunker` to make things more clear . 
https://plnkr.co/edit/dL1DPa50mdZtmaJCwcIO?p=preview

As far as I can Understand ,there is no error other than missing some script files.

```
    <html lang="en" ng-app="Euclid">
        <body ng-controller="mainController" ng-cloak>
            <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="../angular-route.js"></script>           //missing
            <script src="/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.1.2.js"></script>  //missing
            <script src="app.js"></script>
            <div class="container">
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

> As Phil said ,it is clear that the reason for the
>   error is the missing of angular-router and angular-bootstrap.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: Then put the solution in your answer. Link-only answers don't help, especially if the link is removed at a later date